# How do you add a custom property to the Playwright config file

Tags: typescript, playwright, playwright-test

I'm trying to add a custom property to a Playwright config file.  I know you can just jam a key/value pair into the non-project *use* section and have it accessible, but I'm trying to get it to work with TypeScript types.  I followed the example for [Parameterized Projects](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-parameterize#parameterized-projects) from the Playwright site, but it seems that only works for *projects*.

What I really want is to be able to add a custom property to the non-project *use* section of the config and be able to override it from a *project*.  Is this possible?  The example above gets close, but it makes doing local development hard.  I just want to set the values in the non-project *use* section and then run a test, without have to muck around with the projects.  (But still have the ability to *override* the non-project values with *project* specific values.)

My goal is to be able to set *projectName* and *dataSourceName* variables that can be specified in the non-project *use* section of the config file yet overridden in a project.

**Update**:
This was a self-inflicted issue!  I overlooked setting the properties as options.  After doing that everything worked as expected.

```
export const test = base.extend<TestOptions>({
    // Define an option and provide a default value.
    // We can later override it in the config.
    // In order to be able to override, you need to define the
    // string like this:
    projectName: ['empty-project-name', { option: true }],
    dataSourceName: ['empty-dataset-name', { option: true }]
});
```

Now If I can only figure out how to do this with a complex object.

Comment: Can you share https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also more importantly, what are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: I want to be able to set custom variables, in the non-project use section, that can be easily changed during development. Those same variables should also be able to be set, per project, but I don't want them to ONLY be set in a project, as using projects for development is cumbersome. These variables should be readily available to tests, either through the fixture mechanism or via TestInfo. (Or some other option I may not be aware of.) I'd also like to avoid using environment variables as they aren't as obvious as setting variables in the playwright.config.ts file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to use a complex object for your configuration, you can do the following:

```
export class DataInfo {
    projectName: string;
    dataSourceName: string;
}

export class TestOptions {
    dataInfo: DataInfo;
};

export const test = base.extend<TestOptions>({
    // Define an option and provide a default value.
    // We can later override it in the config.
    dataInfo: [{
        projectName: 'empty-project-name',
        dataSourceName: 'empty-dataset-name'
    },  { option: true }]
});
```

The caveat with this approach, is that the entire object, *dataInfo* will be overridden.  You can't just override one of its properties.

(I received this answer directly from the Playwright team via GitHub.)